# Adverb for indicating the coming statement being more important than the previous one

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am working on an academic text, specifically in the conclusions section, where I am stuck trying to formulate something like this:

> "*we have demonstrated a new model for X using Y and Z. Additionally and [>>missing word/idiom<<] , we show different ways to utilize such a model and evaluate the predictive performance of the model by ...*"

So the idea I am trying to convey here is: yes, we show a new model, that's cool, but what's more important here is that we show an alternative way of using this model, which would give more utility since it avoids certain shortcomings.

I thought about synonyms of important, but I am having a difficult time finding a balance between stressing the importance of the second sentence and completely disregarding the first sentence.

I hope it's clear enough, otherwise I'll try to elaborate more

Comment: Probably no sw.  Try "even more important" And take the apostrophe out of it"s.  it's means it is.

Comment: @Xanne the apostrophe was just muscle memory.. I didn't c/p but thanks for the warning

Comment: To balance 'additionally', 'more importantly' is adverbial.

Comment: Just say "And moreover, ..." or "And what's more, ..." maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "we have demonstrated a new model for X using Y and Z. Additionally
>   and ***crucially***, we show different ways to utilize such
>   a model and evaluate the predictive performance of the model by ..."

ODO:

> **[crucially](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/crucially)**
>   *ADVERB*
>   With decisive or vital importance.
>
> [sentence
>   adverb]
>   ‘crucially, recipients of these funds would be required to
>   place their work in the public domain’

Answer (score 1):

Many of the single word answers (for example "predominantly") sound a bit contrived and heavy going - though "fundamentally" would probably work.

A neater solution might be a some/more/most adverb structure. The simplest answer of "most importantly" is a nice way of doing it, though "most significantly" would be a good alternative in the context as quoted.